# How to show column names when there is no data in ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid-angular

When no data is returned, ag-grid shows No Rows To Show message. I am okay with the message but along with it, I would like to see the column names in the header even when there is no data. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.